# Xamarin views are overlapped by the UINavigationBar when set to be translucent

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uinavigationbar, translucency

I have a Xamarin.Forms app and want to set the NavigationBar to be translucent. But when I do, I get a strange behavior with the Xamarin views:

ListViews or TableViews behave correctly. But when I wrap them in a [RefreshView](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/refreshview-xamarin-forms/), they are overlapped by the UINavigationBar.

```
-- TRANSLUCENCY WITHOUT REFRESHVIEW: OKAY

<ContentPage>
    <ListView>
        ...
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

```
-- TRANSLUCENCY WITHOUT REFRESHVIEW: BUGGY

<ContentPage>
    <RefreshView>     <----
        <ListView>
            ...
        </ListView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

[image: Xamarin.Forms views hide behind the UINavigationBar if set to be translucent.]

Am I missing something?

- Repro on GitHub: https://github.com/awaescher/xamarin-repro
- How to make a translucent NavigationBar: https://xamgirl.com/transparent-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: That's strange , I will check the shared github project . If good solution will update here to discuss .

Answer (score 0):

We can use `navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent` to achieve that .

`NavigateFromMenu` method modified as follow :

```
case (int)MenuItemType.TranslucentWithoutRefreshView:
    MenuPages.Add(id, CreateTranslucentNavigationPage(new TranslucentWithRefreshPage(),false));
    break;
case (int)MenuItemType.TranslucentWithRefreshView:
    MenuPages.Add(id, CreateTranslucentNavigationPage(new TranslucentWithRefreshPage(),true));
    break;
```

Then in `CreateTranslucentNavigationPage` method :

```
private Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage CreateTranslucentNavigationPage(Xamarin.Forms.Page page, bool value)
{
    var navigationPage = new Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage(page);
    if (value)
    {
        navigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
        navigationPage.BarTextColor = Color.Black;
    }
    //Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific.NavigationPage.SetIsNavigationBarTranslucent(navigationPage, true);
    return navigationPage;
}
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping out Jiang. However this is not what I'm trying to do. Setting the BackgroundColor is on thing but I want to have translucent (not transparent) navigation bars to build effects like those: https://imgur.com/vV5EmGm

Comment: @Waescher Got it, that's strange . I will have a check with this , if good news will update here .